# How to get the status of a service by return value of"svcs serviceName" on Solaris?

Tags: service, solaris

```
root@test:~# svcs serviceName
STATE          STIME    FMRI
disabled       21:29:14 svc:/application/serviceName:default
root@test:~#  echo $?
0
```

I want to get the status of serviceName by the return value of command line. But svcs return 0 either the service is up or down.
How can I get it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command return value is meant to report if the command run successfully or not. Moreover, there are more states for a service than "up" or "down".

Nevertheless, you can achieve what you want with this shell (ksh & bash) function

```
function svc_up
{
    [[ "$(svcs -Ho state $1)" == online ]]
}
```